# CodeIgnitor 4 Class "Locale" not found

Tags: php, macos, codeigniter, xampp

I am trying to run CodeIgniter 4 in MAC os

I installed XAMPP with php8.2.4.
Then i installed CodeIgniter 4 starter app using composer

and when i run my app it shows

```
Error

Class "Locale" not found 


SYSTEMPATH/CodeIgniter.php at line 194

187 
188         // Run this check for manual installations
189         if (! is_file(COMPOSER_PATH)) {
190             $this->resolvePlatformExtensions(); // @codeCoverageIgnore
191         }
192 
193         // Set default locale on the server
194         Locale::setDefault($this->config->defaultLocale ?? 'en');
195 
196         // Set default timezone on the server
197         date_default_timezone_set($this->config->appTimezone ?? 'UTC');
198 
199         $this->initializeKint();
200     }
```

I searched the error and found solutions.
According to that i un commented the line `extension=php_intl.dll` and then restart xampp server but the error is still showing.

Comment: `.dll` files are for windows libraries, you should check to see if there is a .so version of php_intl available in your XAMPP install.

Comment: No i checked that, Also i switched to MAMP Pro and the error is gone